# getting "only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause" error while it's used only once

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I am creating a database table with the following sql:

```
CREATE  TABLE `cs3_ds1` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL ,
`TIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`USER` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`TIME1` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`TIME2` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`INSERT_TIME` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
 ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Although I am using the current timestamp as default in one column only, But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1293: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

why I am getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure you want that column to be `NULLable` as well as having a default?

Comment: @Dems Sorry about that, it should be NOT NULL. But i was trying different things to see if it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL auto initialises TIMESTAMP Columns with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so your first column `TIME` has the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Added as default. Therefore by the time you explicitly add a DEFAULT to a column one already exists. You either need to change the order your columns are defined:

```
CREATE  TABLE `silas`.`cs3_ds1` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL ,
`INSERT_TIME` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`TIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`USER` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`TIME1` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
`TIME2` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
 ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Or add defaults to your other timestamp columns:

```
CREATE  TABLE `silas`.`cs3_ds1` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL ,
`TIME` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`USER` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
`TIME1` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`TIME2` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`INSERT_TIME` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
 ENGINE = InnoDB
```

See the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your MYSQL version. Your MYSQL version might be other thatn 5.6. This issue is happening due to a limitation in MYSQL version 5.5. You need to update the version to 5.6.

Below is how I enquired this issue

I was getting this error in adding a table in MYSQL

Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause My new MYSQL
table looks something like this.

create table table_name (col1 int(5) auto_increment primary key, col2 varchar(300), col3 varchar(500), col4 int(3), col5 tinyint(2), col6 timestamp default current_timestamp, col7 timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp, col8 tinyint(1) default 0, col9 tinyint(1) default 1);
After some time of reading about changes in different MYSQL versions and some of the googling. I found out that there was some changes that were made in MYSQL version 5.6 over version 5.5.

This article will help you to resolve the issue. http://www.oyewiki.com/MYSQL/Incorrect-table-definition-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this error also, but that's because I'm running < PHP 5.6.5. According to the docs for PHP 5.6.5, this restriction has been lifted:

> Previously, at most one TIMESTAMP column per table could be automatically initialized or 
>   updated to the current date and time. This restriction has been lifted. Any TIMESTAMP 
>   column definition can have any combination of DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses. In addition, these clauses now can be used with DATETIME column definitions. For more information, see Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME.

See MySQL's docs for more information. Specifically under the "Data Type Nodes" section if you follow this link: [Changes in MySQL 5.6.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html)